# Is there a way to submit a Google Dataproc PySpark job on a cluster for .ipynb files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook on a Google Dataproc cluster. When you are using the notebook it gives an output on the execution of each cell.

I have to submit a PySpark job on the cluster. The job takes a .py file as an input. Screenshot attached below

[image: Pyspark Submit Job]

When I enter the path of a .ipynb file it gives the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/tmp/job-e4811479-cell2cell1/Customer_Churn_(Cell2Cell)_Parallel.ipynb
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.error(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:657)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:221)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:116)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:907)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:81)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I am assuming that we can only submit .py files as a job on the cluster. Also converting .ipynb to .py is not feasible for me due to the nature of the code. I want the output of each cell.

Is there any way in which I can submit a .ipynb file on the cluster? Or do I need to make a .py file to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot spark submit a notebook file i.e. ipynb.

You should convert it to py file then submit it on spark dataproc cluster.

The output of spark submit can write multiple outputs to GCS but will return only one output.

So you can create an object on GCS for each output and have your result contained in the bucket.